# Increment global variable inside function

Tags: javascript

Can someone tell me why the global variable is not affecting? the local variable in function works. But not outside the function.

```
let increment = 0;
button.addEventListener("click", function(){
    increment++;
    console.log(increment); // Works!


});

console.log(increment); // Not incrementing
```

Comment: Have you actually called that function?  For instance, by pressing the button?

Comment: Yes when pressing the button, console.log(increment) inside function logs 1,2,3,4,5 etc. But console.log(increment) outside function logs 0,0,0,0 not incrementing

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), visit the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), and read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  In this case, a minimal example would have to explain how you call that external `console.log` outside the listener, but still know exactly *when* to call it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This version might help demonstrate what's happening:

```js
let increment = 0;

const button = document.getElementById('foo');
const output = document.getElementById('output');

const updateOutput = function() {
  output.innerHTML = `Value is ${increment} at ${new Date().toString().substring(16, 24)}`;
}

button.addEventListener("click", function(){
    increment++;
    updateOutput();
});
setInterval(updateOutput, 1000)

console.log(`External call, value: ${increment}`);
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
<hr/>
<div><button id="foo">Increment</button></div>
```

Choose "Run code snippet" to see it in action.  It tells you the current value of the (global) `increment` variable every second.  It also updates when you click the button and thereby increase the value.  Both functions are accessing the same global `increment` variable.

Comment: Thank you! it helped me alot now!

Answer (score 2):

This is because `addEventListener` works asynchronously. The `console.log` statement at the last line of your code gets executed before the callback of your event listener is run and thus the value of your `increment` variabe is still 0.

Comment: oh how can I affect the global variable when clicking the button?

Comment: As far as I can tell, you *are* changing that global variable.  When are you calling that external `console.log`?

Comment: @MATKALI You are actually affecting the global variable. After the button has been clicked and your event listener has run, your increment variable has a value of 1. It's just that your last console.log will always be executed before your event listener callback , so the output is 0.

Comment: I editet the code now. I removed console.log from inside the function. Now it's outside the function only but it keeps logging 0 only.

Comment: @MATKALI The problem is still the same: Your console.log statement gets executed immidiately while your event listener is only executed after the button is clicked.

Comment: It should only log that initial value once in either version of the code.  Inside the click listener it will be updated.